# Flyspell: Ignore comments in LaTeX-documents

Tags: latex, auctex, flyspell

Whenever I run `flyspell-buffer` (using hunspell) in a LaTeX-document, my comments marked with % are spell-checked aswell, although I don't want them to be spell-checked. The simplest solution `(setq ispell-check-comments nil)` does not do anything. I also tried to let ispell ignore all lines commented out by % with

```
    (defun flyspell-ignore-TeX-comments ()
    "Ignore lines starting with %."
    (not (string-match "^ *%" (thing-at-point 'line t))))
    (put 'text-mode 'flyspell-mode-predicate 'flyspell-ignore-TeX-comments)
```

This did not do anything either. The comments are recognized as such, though, since they are colored by `font-lock-comment-face`. I have explicitly turned off `flyspell-prog-mode` with `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'turn-off-flyspell t)`.

And now for the weirdest part. When I go to `Tools -> Spell-Checking -> Customize`, emacs tells me that  `ispell Check Comments` is toggled *off* and if I spell-check my document with `Tools -> Spell-Checking -> Spell-Check Buffer`, they are ignored as intended, but if I run `M-x flyspell-buffer RET`, they are not!

Does anyone have an idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`flyspell` and `ispell` are two different packages.

Yes, `flyspell` does use a bit of APIs of `ispell`.

But it does not mean you can set any flag of `ispell` to tweak `flyspell`. It's very possible the flag has no impact on the limited APIs which `flyspell` uses.

To use your predicate, you need run `(flyspell-mode 1)` at least once.

It's because `flyspell-mode-on` will load your per major mode predicate `flyspell-ignore-TeX-comments` into `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate`.

Code from `flyspell-mode-on`,
[image]

`flyspell-mode` and `flyspell-prog-mode` are two minor modes to automate the spelling check. You can only turn on one of them.

By default, they are not turned on. So I don't understand why you need turn off `flyspell-prog-mode`.

I'm not sure `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'turn-off-flyspell t)` can turn off `flyspell-prog-mode`. To turn off `flyspell-prog-mode`, you need `(flyspell-prog-mode -1)`.

BTW, you can use https://github.com/redguardtoo/wucuo instead of `flyspell-mode` or `flyspell-prog-mode`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I now switched to wucuo. There, you can just set the font-faces wucuo is supposed to check (and I set them to ```font-lock-string-face```. Simply turning flyspell-mode on did not work, unfortunately, but that might be because there's something wrong with my function.